# Can https address end with "?"

Tags: https, facebook-page

I am amateur, so please be patient :)
I want to put an image as a welcome page on fan page. I created app, in which I insert a picture from website. This website has https address (my picture too :) ). But canvas URL must point to a directory (end with / or ?). On my site picture cannot ends with / - 404 Not found. When it ends with "?" , it works, but facebook doesnt appear it. Why? Please answer me.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook accepts documents, not just a single image.

Make an HTML document, for example index.html. Put the image in the document. Publish this in a folder somewhere, and configure the App to use this URL, which now ends in a slash.